# How to organise team work on mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, database

How to organise team work on mysql databases? Probably, something like svn, but for databases

Comment: Now we use sql dump on svn. And if someone change database, it should make new dump and commit it.

Before the work beginning, developer should check for updates and if they are, he should update his database from updated dump

Comment: I'm afraid that is the way to go if every user needs access to 'his database version' while developing. You could automate this with dumping before svn and loading after svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/

migration scripts we generate with MySQL Workbench and store it in SVN

Comment: Also, for small and simple databases will aproach this tool: http://code.google.com/p/mygrate/, but it not stable, yet

Answer (score 1):

SVN, Microsoft TFS or any other source control should do fine. Give each developer his/her own database instance for development purposes. Use continuous integration / automated builds for large teams and databases that need frequent change.